# Celebrate/Joi returns in case of error HTML instead of JSON

Tags: node.js, express, validation, joi

Currently I've celebrate installed on my Node/Express server. Whenever certain validation criteria is not met, it receive the error in an HTML file instead of a JSON object. I am using the `const app = express()` as documented. How can I return a JSON object instead?

**server.js**

```
const { errors } = require('celebrate');

app.use(errors());
```

**profile-route.js**

```
router.post('/', [auth, celebrate({ body: Validate.profileSchema })], async (req, res) => {
const {
name,
} = req.body;

try {
    let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

    if (profile) {
        profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate({ user: req.user.id }, { $set: profileFields }, { new: true });
        return res.json(profile);
    }

    profile = new Profile(profileFields);

    await profile.save();

    res.json(profile);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json(error.message);
}
});
```

**validation-schemas.js**

```
const profileSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).max(30).required(),
});
```

**output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Error: &quot;name&quot; length must be at least 3 characters long<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you are calling app.use(errors()) after you've declared your routes.

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { Joi, celebrate, errors } from "celebrate";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
const schema = Joi.object({
  email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  password: Joi.string().required(),
}).required();

app.post("/session", celebrate({ body: schema }), (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const { token } = login(email, password);
  res.status(201).send({ token });
});

app.use(errors()); // <--- Should be here

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listens on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```